# Reactjs API error 'TypeError: fetch(...).then(...).then(...).done is not a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

loggingIn() is my onClick listener.

```
loggingIn(){
            fetch("http://sampleurl.com", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: this.state.username,
                    password: this.state.password,
                })
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
                console.log(responseData);
            if (responseData.response === 1) {
              alert("Success");

            } else {
                alert("Username or password is incorrect");
            }

        })
        .done();
    }
```

Does anybody know why it gives me an error?. When I use this code to react native it works just fine but when I integrate it in reactjs it gives me this error

```
`TypeError: fetch(...).then(...).then(...).done is not a function`
```

Comment: Remove the `.done()`.

Answer (score 5):

fetch() returns a Promise, on which you can call then() to get the response and catch() to get any errors that were thrown.

Replace `.done()` with something like `.catch((error) => console.error(error))`.

See here for details: [Networking in React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)

Comment: ....but he said above code works fine in React Native...The problem is only when integrate with ReactJs

Comment: I doubt it works, or it works because React native ignored the done somehow. The Promise that fetch() returns doesn't have a done function.

Comment: The .done() bit of the Promise protocol that React Native supports isn't implemented in babel/browsers (yet).

Answer (score 3):

that problem arises due to missing of the catch block. Mine was resolved after adding the catch block.

```
 fetch(URL, config)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((data) => {})
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```